Right-column "featured on Meta" section formatting is broken
Here's what it looks like (Brave latest, Ubuntu 22.04) for me:

And on MSE (so this isn't SO-only problem):

The section headers look obviously misplaced vertically, almost overlapping with section dividers.
It's probably the least important problem of SE sites now, but maybe this also means we can get this fixed just in a few months?
